# 3 Dimensional Combination of One-hot Vectors

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I need to create a 3-dimensional list of all pairs of 3x1 one-hot vectors in python, but I'm having trouble generating the array.  I'm trying to do it using `np.arange`, but I haven't quite been able to get that working.  For example, my one-hot vectors are: `A=[1,0,0] B=[0,1,0] and C=[0,0,1]`.  The output I need is the three dimensional array `[[A,A],[A,B],[A,C],[B,A],[B,B],[B,C],[C,A],[C,B],[C,C]]` That is, a 9x2x3 array consisting of all combinations of pairs of one-hot vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a NumPy way with mesh creation of those pairwise combinations of indices -

```
# Create input array from those vectors
a = np.array([A,B,C])
n = len(a)

# Create grid of indices
r,c = np.mgrid[:n,:n]

# Index for final output
out = a[np.c_[c.ravel().T,r.ravel()]]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [365]: A = [1,0,0]
     ...: B = [0,1,0]
     ...: C = [0,0,1]

In [367]: out
Out[367]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```

**Approach #2 (for performance)**

We can use the fact that the inputs are one-hot vectors to gain performance, specially for large number of vectors with greater lengths by initializing the output array and assigning ones into it. The trick to using the one-hotness is getting those one-value unique indices per vectors with `argmax`. We will use these indices to assign into output at only those specific places. The implementation would be -

```
def multidim_hotvectors(a): # a is input list of vectors = [A,B,C]
    n = len(a)
    idx = np.array([np.argmax(i) for i in a])
    putval = (idx[:,None] == np.arange(n)).astype(int)
    out = np.zeros((n,n,2,n),dtype=int)
    out[:,:,0,:] = putval[:,None,:]
    out[:,:,1,:] = putval
    out.shape = (n**2,2,-1)
    return out
```

#### Runtime test

Other approaches for `a = [A,B,C]` -

```
# @Engineero's soln
np.array([c for c in itertools.product(a, repeat=2)])

# @B. M.'s soln
np.array(list(itertools.product(a,a)))
```

Function to setup input list of one-hot vectors -

```
def create_input_list_vectors(L):
    d = (np.random.choice(L,L,replace=0)[:,None] == range(L)).astype(int)
    return list(map(list,d))
```

Timings -

```
In [359]: a = create_input_list_vectors(L=5)

In [360]: %timeit np.array([c for c in itertools.product(a, repeat=2)])
     ...: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.product(a,a)))
     ...: %timeit multidim_hotvectors(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.4 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.5 µs per loop

In [361]: a = create_input_list_vectors(L=20)

In [362]: %timeit np.array([c for c in itertools.product(a, repeat=2)])
     ...: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.product(a,a)))
     ...: %timeit multidim_hotvectors(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 966 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 967 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop

In [363]: a = create_input_list_vectors(L=100)

In [364]: %timeit np.array([c for c in itertools.product(a, repeat=2)])
     ...: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.product(a,a)))
     ...: %timeit multidim_hotvectors(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 98.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools as it
combos = [c for c in it.product([A, B, C], repeat=2)]
# combos = [([1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]),
#           ([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]),
#           ([1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]),
#           ([0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]),
#           ([0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]),
#           ([0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]),
#           ([0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]),
#           ([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]),
#           ([0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am unfamiliar with numpy here is a one/two liner solution.

To make it easy we will take `A='a'`, `B='b'` and `C='c'`

Given all your 'hot vector' (not sure what they are but anyway) are stored in one vector:

```
>>> options = [A,B,C]
>>> result = [x,y for x in options for y in options]
>>> print(result)
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'a'],
 ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'b'],
 ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c']]
```

*Note the newlines in the print result are to make it fit in the screen*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with itertools  :

```
A,B,C=np.eye(3,dtype=int)
import itertools 
l=list(itertools.product((A,B,C),(A,B,C)))
a923=np.array(l)
```

or directly in numpy :

```
points=np.array([
[1,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[0,0,1]])
n,dim=points.shape
indices=np.indices((n,n))

# indice.T :
# array([[[0, 0],
#         [1, 0],
#         [2, 0]],
# 
#        [[0, 1],
#         [1, 1],
#         [2, 1]],
# 
#        [[0, 2],
#         [1, 2],
#         [2, 2]]])

res = points[indices.T].reshape(n*n,2,dim)
```

Comment: If I use a generic set, say : `A = [0,1,0] ; B = [1,0,0]; C = [0,0,1]`, the output seems different from the expected one for the second one. Check again?